# How to split string into words including delimiters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

How can I split a text into words in .NET, returning both the words and their separators and punctuation marks.

Input:

```
"Hello world! What's up?"
```

Output: 'Hello', ' ', 'world', '!', ' ','What's',' ','up','?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?=[^\w'])|(?<=[^\w'])
```

You can split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/15

Answer (score 0):

var output = Regex.Split(input, "([^A-Z0-9])", RegexOptions.IgnoreSpace);

Answer (score -2):

Use this regular expression:

```
'(?=[^\w'])|(?<=[^\w'])`
```

Comment: @vks It was apparently posted about the same time, which can happen, Since yours has an explanation, been marked as the answer and up-voted, don't worry about it...